# How to connect and fetch data from one micro service to another micro services

Tags: java, microservices

I am using spring cloud for API gateway I want to know how can we communicate one microservice to another also fetch data from any other microservices

Comment: I recommend you look through the [official docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/). In short, you need to set up a Discovery service in which you register your microservices.

Comment: What is the deployment environment? Are you using kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `OpenFeign`, Check the documentation in spring

[Spring Documentation for OpenFeign](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-openfeign)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, as they aren't considered valid answers. This is best done in a comment (or not at all, as documentation recommendation questions are off-topic, and the OP hasn't asked a specific question, just a general inquiry).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Even Spring official documentation?

Comment: Point being, just a link to docs isn't answering anything. Regardless of source of documentation. Plus, doc links age and rot over time. The one thing I like in your answer is calling out OpenFeign, but again... that's just a hint at something to look at, nothing specific. If the OP asked a specific question, and you provided a detailed answer around it, that would be great. In this case, though, the question is generic and very broad (off-topic as written), and the best thing to do is provide feedback accordingly (and optionally provide a link via comment)